Is it possible to install a specific version of a formula from a homebrew tap?
I have looked at the answers to this question, but the syntax brew install path/to/formula/in/tap@1.5.1 results in No available formula or cask, so it does not seem to work with taps.
I have also seen the git-based solutions which involve checking out an older version of the local tap clone. Those work but they're a little cumbersome.
Is there a more direct way to install an older version of a formula from a tap, without rewinding the git history of the tap to the commit that introduced a particular version?

Yes, it's possible to install a specific formula version from a Homebrew tap, but it requires a few extra steps. Homebrew itself doesn’t natively support versioning for all formulas. However, if the version is available within a tap or an older commit, you can still install it.
Here’s how you can do it:
Find the commit of the version you want: Check the formula’s git history in the tap repository to find the commit hash corresponding to the version you need.
Check out the tap at that commit:
Install the specific version:
Pin the formula (optional):

Some old major versions are added separate formula or cask but not minors. If you cannot search specific version on the list, and then there is no way to use homebrew directry get the versioned formula or cask and should create into the third party tap.
